# C++ object as an Objective-C++ property

Tags: c++, objective-c++

I want to declare a C++ property inside my Objective-C class.

What kind of attributes should I set it to? It seems that `strong` or `retain` will lead to an error saying that it is not an object.

How could I manage its memory properly?

Comment: A short complete example, if possible, might help.  It sounds like your question is not just what attributes to use, but is broader: how to manage the C++ object's memory.  Is the C++ object owned by the Objective-C class?  Is the Objective-C class actually Objective-C++?  You would be limited in what you can do with a C++ object in Objective-C (not Objective-C++) code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are right, the property cannot be `weak`, `strong`, or `retained`; for that it would have to be a pointer to an Objective-C object.  If you don't use any attributes on a C++ property, it will default to `unsafe_unretained,assign,atomic`.

A few other things to consider, assuming the Objective-C(++) object controls the lifetime of the C++ property:

- Because you can't do much with a C++ object in Objective-C, the
  property is mostly useful in Objective-C++ code, where you can mix
  Objective-C and C++.
- Because you have to manage the property's memory on your own, you
  need a custom setter.
- Because the property defaults to `atomic`, you need to use
  synchronization in the setter and need a custom getter, too.  You
  could declare it `nonatomic`, in which case you would not need to
  synchronize and would not need a custom getter.
- You can implement `dealloc` to ensure the C++ object is freed when
  the Objective-C++ object goes away.

Here's some useful documentation from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html.

And here is a quick example.  Let's say the C++ class you are using for the property is called `MyCPP`.  In a header you could have:

```
@interface ClassOCPP : NSObject

// This property can only be used in Objective-C++ code
#ifdef __cplusplus
@property /*(unsafe_unretained,assign,atomic)*/ MyCPP * myCPP;
#endif

// Other stuff may be usable in regular Objective-C code.

@end
```

Implementation could be as follows (in a `.mm` file; remember, it's Objective-C++):

```
@implementation ClassOCPP
{
    MyCPP * _myCPP;
}
-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    _myCPP = NULL;
    return self;
}

-(void)setMyCPP:(MyCPP*)newVal {
    @synchronized(self) {
        delete _myCPP;  // it's OK to delete a NULL pointer
        _myCPP = newVal;
    }
}

-(MyCPP*)myCPP {
    return _myCPP;
}

-(void)dealloc {
    puts("De-allocating ClassOCPP.");
    delete _myCPP;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, you need to manage it like any other C++ object, so just use `assign` as the attribute, and you should be good.